# SQL Union query needs to be added to

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query where I check if the person logging in is connected to a apartment (unit) as either an owner, or a resident. It looks like below:

```
select m.* from member m
inner join unit_contract_member ucm on ucm.member_id = m.id
inner join unit_contract uc on uc.id = ucm.contract_id
inner join unit u on u.id = uc.unit_id
where m.usr = _usr
and m.pwd = _pwd
and u.community_id = _communityId
and m.active = true
and uc.active = true

union all

select m.* from member m
inner join unit_owner uo on uo.member_id = m.id
inner join unit u on u.id = uo.unit_id
where m.usr = _usr
and m.pwd = _pwd
and u.community_id = _communityId
and m.active = true;
```

This query works fine. However, I now need to add the possibility of an apartment having authorized members (pretty much another type of owner), and in theory, the query would look like this (added section at the end of the query):

```
select m.* from member m
inner join unit_contract_member ucm on ucm.member_id = m.id
inner join unit_contract uc on uc.id = ucm.contract_id
inner join unit u on u.id = uc.unit_id
where m.usr = _usr
and m.pwd = _pwd
and u.community_id = _communityId
and m.active = true
and uc.active = true

union all

select m.* from member m
inner join unit_owner uo on uo.member_id = m.id
inner join unit u on u.id = uo.unit_id
where m.usr = _usr
and m.pwd = _pwd
and u.community_id = _communityId
and m.active = true;

union all

select m.* from member m
inner join unit_authorized_member uam on uam.member_id = m.id
inner join unit u on u.id = uam.unit_id
where m.usr = _usr
and m.pwd = _pwd
and u.community_id = _communityId
and m.active = true;
```

However, the last UNION ALL dosent play well and throws an error. What can I do to get this expected functionality? Any ideas?

Hoping someone out there is better at SQL than me. But since your average badger is, Im guessing that wont be too hard to find :)

Bob

Comment: What error is thrown?

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'union all   select m.* from member m  inner join unit_authorized_member uam on u' at line 1

Comment: remove the semi colon in the 2nd union.  Semicolon means I'm done with this SQL.  then the Union all is looked at by the engine, and it thinks, union all to what? there's nothing before this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

get rid of the semi-colon at the end of `and m.active = true;`

I tested this with some sample data on my server and the semicolon throws it off as 'error near union'

```
select m.* from member m
inner join unit_contract_member ucm on ucm.member_id = m.id
inner join unit_contract uc on uc.id = ucm.contract_id
inner join unit u on u.id = uc.unit_id
where m.usr = _usr
and m.pwd = _pwd
and u.community_id = _communityId
and m.active = true
and uc.active = true

union all

select m.* from member m
inner join unit_owner uo on uo.member_id = m.id
inner join unit u on u.id = uo.unit_id
where m.usr = _usr
and m.pwd = _pwd
and u.community_id = _communityId
and m.active = true

union all

select m.* from member m
inner join unit_authorized_member uam on uam.member_id = m.id
inner join unit u on u.id = uam.unit_id
where m.usr = _usr
and m.pwd = _pwd
and u.community_id = _communityId
and m.active = true
```